# jquery: delete element by specifying data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok. so i have got stuck in a simple situation. I want to delete `<li>` elements present inside some `<ul>`, but from its `data-*` attribute.

I tried the code but dont know why its not working. Check out my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/refevoyo/1/edit).

Please specify where i was going wrong (because i need to learn from it).

I know its much easy for you all... but i am not able to make out... so needed your help. Thanks..

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script>
  function deleteElement(id)
  {
    $("ul li").data("id", id).remove();
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li data-id="3">3<input type="button" onclick="deleteElement(3)" value="delete"></li>
  <li data-id="31">31<input type="button" onclick="deleteElement(31)" value="delete"></li>
  <li data-id="32">32<input type="button" onclick="deleteElement(32)" value="delete"></li>
  <li data-id="33">33<input type="button" onclick="deleteElement(33)" value="delete"></li>
  <li data-id="41">41<input type="button" onclick="deleteElement(41)" value="delete"></li>
  <li data-id="42">42<input type="button" onclick="deleteElement(42)" value="delete"></li>
  <li data-id="43">43<input type="button" onclick="deleteElement(43)" value="delete"></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code should be posted **here**, and not just in a linked jsbin.

Comment: With your code structure, you might as well remove the parent of the clicked item `$(this).parent().remove()`

Comment: Sure sir. I am just updating my question here, again.

Comment: Ok sir. I have got the answer. Both of you were right. I am bit confused which to mark as accepted. Therefore, i upvoted both the answers. Thanks for your helping me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can select by attributes:

```
$("ul li[data-id=" + id + "]").remove();
```

Comment: @shree202 - no problem, be sure to mark an answer if it accomplished what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('ul li[data-id="' + id + '"]').remove();
```

Or filter, if you don't want to concatenate the variable into the selector:

```
$('ul li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('id') == id;
}).remove();
```